# AJAX response page: CSS lost partially?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I'm wondering how I could attach CSS and JS into my sidebar. The sidebar is part of the bootstrap UI and has JS and CSS in it.

Sidebar has slide-down- menus built of li-elements and links. Naturally it worked well before ajax.

File lists2.php has 50% of it php assembyling arrays and the rest just echoes the arrays into special drop-down menus and links.

The ajax tries to change contents of the sidebar div of index.php: index has the same css- and js-files in it so they should have the same files. But I understood that the resulting data of ajax is in different scope than index.php.

I already tried:
- Including css- and js-files in the lists2.php
- Trying to append at least single css-file in the ajax, as you see below
- And some other things I dont even remember anymore

This should be basics, but how can I figure it out?

Thanks a lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "lists2.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function() {
      $(".sidebarcontent").text("Loading..");
    },
    success: function(lists) {
      $(".sidebarcontent").html(lists);
      $("head").append('<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to pre-load the CSS and JS files in the head normally and then just load the HTML/PHP so it could use the cached scripts?

Comment: They are loaded in index.php's head etc. of course, did you mean that? despite that, they dont work for ajax-loaded content in the sidebar.

Comment: Maybe the issue is because you are appending a head tag in the wrong file. You must remember that AJAX always will take the file that you are passing over your ajax handler and in this case, you are adding the '<link>' over your lists2.php and not in your head of your other document